# mock socket.io-client with jest when socket used in an es6 class

Tags: unit-testing, sockets, mocking, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests with jest and I want to mock the socket.io-client module so I can test an es6 class that's using it.

Here's a simplified version of the class:

```
import io from "socket.io-client"

export default class BotClient {
    io: SocketIOClientStatic
    client: SocketIOClient.Socket | undefined
    connected: boolean = false
    attemptReconnection: boolean = true
    
    constructor() {
        this.io = io
    }
    
    init() {
        try {
            this.reconnectToApi()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
    
    reconnectToApi(): void {
        
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.client?.connected || !this.attemptReconnection) {
                this.connected = true
                this.addHooks()
                clearInterval(interval)
                return
            }
            this.client = this.io.connect("myurl")
        }, 5000)
    }
```

And I wrote my test to mock the socket.io-client module and return a custom implementation object that returns a mock function for the `connect` method like this:

```
import BotClient from "../src/lib/BotClient"
import io from "socket.io-client"


const mockClient = {
    connect: jest.fn(() => {
        connected: true
    }),
}

jest.mock("socket.io-client", () => {
    return mockClient
})


test("client will attempt connection until told to stop", () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()

    const reconnectSpy = jest.spyOn(client, "reconnectToApi")
    const hookSpy = jest.spyOn(client, "addHooks")

    client.init("my-bot-id")

    const callCount = 3
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000 * callCount)

    expect(reconnectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(hookSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

But when I try to run the test I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined

I'm looking over the jest [docs on mocking modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) and using custom implementations and it seems like I'm doing it right, but obviously I'm not :/ I feel like I'm tripping over information in the docs.

How would I do this correctly? What part am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Did you find an answer ? i followed exactly the same steps, arrived exactly at this point.

Comment: Oh no! I did find the answer but I don't work for that company any more so I can't look back at the code. It may be worth opening an issue in socket.io's repository.

Comment: I actually ended up writing my own jest mock for the socket.io and exposing it as a global, in the fashion of "global.socketIoServer.on(event, data)" and "await global.socketIoServer.emit(event, data)" :) thanks a lot for your answer @chris